# Participation factors/modal mass is zero with cyclic symmetry

Tags: abaqus, frequency-analysis

currently I'm running an Eigen frequency analysis with cyclic symmetry. When running the model, all seems to go according to what I expected. Eigen Frequencies are in line with manufactured products for all cyclic modes. However, for cyclic modes > 1 the participation factors and the modal masses become zero. I have run also the example problem from the manual "Analysis of a rotating fan using substructures and cyclic symmetry", and I see the same result; both participation factors and the modal masses become zero. Can someone explain to me why these become zero?

Thank you in advance, regards Tim

I tried newer versions of the Abaqus solver to see if it was a bug.
I read the manual and ran input files from the manual. I tried to see of there are different solvers then Lanczos or Guyan might cause this. No succes. Input file directly from the manual gives same result (but also uses Lanczos and Guyan technique).
I tried google and deliberate with colleagues.

Comment: Status update; other FE have the same result; i.e. all zeros. Ansys APDL gives way more information then the Abaqus user guide; for future reference, please check out the 'ansys mechanical apdl advanced analysis guide', things will become more clear there.